# How do I connect my local java application to cassandra running in a container on a server

Tags: java, docker, server, cassandra

I want to connect to cassandra running on server in a container. Can anyone please give a simple code for that.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to do this in java, here is just one small example (there are lots of variants to this). FYI, this is using DSE. You'll need the java drivers as well to make this work.

```
  public void connect(String nodes, String username, String password, String keyspace) {

    cluster = Cluster.builder()
     .addContactPoints(nodes.split(","))
     .withCredentials(username, password)
     .build();

session = cluster.connect(keyspace);

Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();

System.out.printf("Connected to cluster: %s\n",
      metadata.getClusterName());

for ( Host host : metadata.getAllHosts() ) {
   System.out.printf("Datacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s\n",
      host.getDatacenter(), host.getAddress(), host.getRack());
 }
}
```

The nodes contain one or more hosts to connect to. It doesn't matter where they are located (physical servers, vms, containers, etc). Those are the initial contact points (typically the seed nodes). Once connected, the entire cluster will be known to the client application where it will spawn connections to all nodes.

Hope this helps you get started.

-Jim

Comment: Will it work if the Cassandra is running on a server and if I just put the IP of server will it connect?